# Problem with updating inner collection in entity EF Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities which contain collections of eachother, so I've updated all values in User entity including this collection, but after save, database saved only properties, and data of inner collection hasn't changed at all

User Entity

```
  public partial class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Password { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
        public int Role { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PlaneModel> PlaneModels { get; set; }
    }
```

Plane Entity

```
public partial class PlaneModel
{ 

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime YearOfProd { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PlanePart> PlaneParts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

User Repository

```
 public void UpdateUser(User user)
    {
        var dbUser = GetAll().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id);
        _context.Entry(dbUser).State = EntityState.Detached;
        _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
        _context.Update(user);
        var userstate = _context.Entry(user).State;
        user.RegistrationDate = dbUser.RegistrationDate;
        user.Role = dbUser.Role;
        user.Password = dbUser.Password;
        var planeState = _context.Entry(user).Collection(p => p.PlaneModels).IsModified;
        foreach(var plane in user.PlaneModels)
        {
            _context.Entry(plane).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        Save();
    }
```

Comment: Are you expecting to update the `User` and its related `PlaneModels` only, or the `PlaneParts` of the `PlaneModel` entity should be updated too?

Comment: Main issue happend with use of eager loading, so I think there was recursive loading of elements, so I've played a lot with tracking of the inner elements and got the desired result, main idea was to update planes in user entity, to add user information in their user collection

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the issue was somewhere else, but now it is working as expected?

Comment: I mean the cause of it yes, but the solution was in here, I had to play a lot with tracking of the objects of inner collection and got desired result

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you configure the fluent api. A many-to-many relationship requires an additional table, which is used to record the relative relationship between the two tables.

```
public class UserPlaneModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Users user { get; set; }
    public int PlaneModelId { get; set; }
    public PlaneModel planeModel { get; set; }
}
```

Other tables should configure a one-to-many relationship with it.

```
public partial class Users
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<PlaneModel> PlaneModels { get; set; }
    public List<UserPlaneModel> userPlaneModels { get; set; }
}
public partial class PlaneModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime YearOfProd { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<PlanePart> PlaneParts { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public List<UserPlaneModel> userPlaneModels { get; set; }
}
```

And configure the realtionship in dbcontext.

```
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PlaneModel> PlaneModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserPlaneModel> userPlaneModels { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserPlaneModel>().HasKey(x=>new { x.UserId,x.PlaneModelId});
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserPlaneModel>().HasOne(x=>x.user)
            .WithMany(x=>x.userPlaneModels).HasForeignKey(x=>x.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserPlaneModel>().HasOne(x => x.planeModel)
            .WithMany(x => x.userPlaneModels).HasForeignKey(x => x.PlaneModelId);
    }
```

Comment: Fluent api was fine, problem was just with tracking of elements, I've experemented a lot with eager loading on this project, and a little bit after understood reason why it's dangerous weapon